# Как уменьшить время работы кода?

Tags: python, циклы, инспекция-кода

Имеется обученная модель, на основе которой необходимо проставить категорию текста из файла и записать данную категорию в другой файл. В файле более 20 000 строк.

```
for schetchik in range(list):
    text = descriptions[schetchik]

    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(descriptions)
    tokenizer.word_index
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(descriptions)

    sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
    data = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen=max_review_len)

    result = model.predict(data)
    prediction = model.predict(np.array(data))
    predicted_label = text_labels[np.argmax(prediction)]
    with open('PREDICT.csv', 'r+') as f:
        f.seek(0, 2)
        f.write(str(predicted_label)+"\n")
    print(text)
    print(predicted_label)
```

Comment: `for text in descriptions:`. Думаю плохая идея открывать и закрывать файл в цикле.

Comment: Если вы используете GPU, можно заменить numpy на [cupy](https://github.com/cupy/cupy)

Comment: А зачем вы два раза делаете model.predict?

Comment: Вы кстати проверьте, что именно у вас время потребляет. Может у вас print время ест, если это именно рабочий код у вас так выглядит.

Comment: predict не убрал после тестирования, использую сверточную сеть

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вы просите нечто типа код-ревью, держите.

`for schetchik in range(list):` - имя переменной у вас `list`?

`for schetchik in range(list): text = descriptions[schetchik]` -> `for text in descriptions`

`tokenizer = Tokenizer();tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words)` - два раза создаёте какой-то сложный объект?

`tokenizer.word_index` - что это?

`sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(descriptions);sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])` - если `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences` не меняет состояния `tokenizer`, то уверены ли вы, что вызывать надо именно так?

`result = model.predict(data)` - зачем?

```
for ... :
    with open('PREDICT.csv', 'r+') as f:
        f.seek(0, 2)
        f.write(str(predicted_label)+"\n")
```

не лучше ли заменить на:

```
with open('PREDICT.csv', 'r+') as f:
    for ... :
        f.write(f'{predicted_label}\n')
```

С учётом инфы, которую вы дали, это максимум, что вы можете получить в ответе. Проверьте, сколько у вас выполняется предсказание, а сколько весь остальной код, мб у вас модель работает 99% времени кода (по моим наблюдениям, при +- средней модели так и есть). Также настройте батчинг данных, перенесите выполнение на gpu, уменьшите модель в 5-10 раз. Готово, профит.